# how can i pass a value to inArray helper in handelbar template from object

Tags: express, handlebars.js

i am using InArray helper to check weather a value is present in array or not and render the block according to result.
if i hardcode the value then its working fine like show below.

```
{{#inArray this.likes "5e20c3d45df5dc29e4a403c3"}}
<button class="btn btn-primary likebtn" value="{{this._id}}">unLike</button>
{{else}}
<button class="btn btn-primary likebtn" value="{{this._id}}">like</button>
{{/inArray}}
```

but i want the value from an object pass while rendering the template. my value is in user_data.user_id.
i tried the below code but its not working .

```
{{#inArray this.likes "{{user_data.user_id}}"}}
<button class="btn btn-primary likebtn" value="{{this._id}}">unLike</button>
{{else}}
<button class="btn btn-primary likebtn" value="{{this._id}}">like</button>
{{/inArray}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create custom hbs helpers.

```
hbs.registerHelper("in_array", function(key, arr, options) {
    if (arr.includes(key)) return options.fn(this);
    else return options.inverse(this);
});
```

And use it in your hbs file like this.

```
{{#in_array key arr}} 
    <h1>{{key}} is present</h1>
{{else}}
    <h1>{{key}} is not present</h1>
{{/in_array}}
```